# How to install python package on GitHub Codespaces without having to rebuild the container?

Tags: python, flask, pip, codespaces, github-codespaces

I copied a template codespace https://github.com/github/codespaces-flask and now whenever I need to add a new package `pip install redis` for example I have to add it to my requirements.txt and rebuild the entire codespace again.

What is the proper way of doing this?

Thank you in advance.

I tried searching GitHub codespaces documentation and following Docker tutorials. I didn't find anything specific enough to answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

Try `pip install -t target_directory` to install directly into a specified folder

Answer (score 0):

Running `pip install package_name` in terminal will have the package installed for your current codespace build. You need not rebuild your codespace for those packages to work.

But do also add `pip install package_name` for all your required packages to  your [requirements.txt](https://github.com/github/codespaces-flask), so that you don't have to manually install these packages the next time you build a new codespace.